# Get complex type properties from PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I trying to build a generic recursive function to iterate all properties / complex properties and return an array of all properties from the following structre:

```
public class Root
{
   [FieldCodeItems(1, EnumFieldCode.INT, "ED", "0204")]
   public int Prop1 { get; set; }
   public Child Child { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    [FieldCodeItems(1, EnumFieldCode.INT, "ED", "0208")]
    public int PropChild1 { get; set; }
    [FieldCodeItems(19, EnumFieldCode.ALPHANUMERIC, "ED", "0208")]
    public string PropChild2 { get; set; }
    public Child1 Child1 { get; set; }
}

public class Child1
{
    [FieldCodeItems(1, EnumFieldCode.INT, "ED", "0211")]
    public int PropChild3 { get; set; }
}

public class MyReturClass
{
    public string FileCode { get; set; }
    public string FieldCode { get; set; }
}
```

I can read all properties from Root class but I can't get the properties from the complex properties:

```
public static List<MyReturClass> GetItems<T>(T obj)
{
    var ret = new List<MyReturClass>();

    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes();
        foreach (Attribute attribute in attributes)
        {
            //here I read values from a custom property
            var tr = (FieldCodeItems)attribute;
            var value = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(obj, null);

            if (value == null) continue;

            ret.Add(new MyReturClass
            {
                FieldCode = tr.FieldCode,
                FileCode = tr.FileCode
            });     
        }
        //If is complex object (Child, Child1 etc)
        if (property.PropertyType.IsClass && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
        {
            //I would like pass the complex property as parameter, but at this moment 
            //the property variable is a PropertyInfo and I need the complex type
            //to get properties values from this object
            GetItems(property); //Error. Also tried with GetItems(property.PropertyType);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I would like pass the complex property as parameter, but at this moment the property variable is a PropertyInfo and I need the complex type to get properties values from this object.
How can I get this object?

I searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573953/c-sharp-reflection-getting-list-of-properties-from-a-propertyinfo), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122835/entity-framework-query-against-complex-type-properties) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48309932/get-property-value-from-propertyinfo) but the solutions don't solve my problem.

**Edit - 03-08-2018**

Finally I found the awswer [here](http://mcgivery.com/c-reflection-get-property-value-of-nested-classes/)

I added this code to solve the problem:

```
//If is complex object (Child, Child1 etc)
if (property.PropertyType.IsClass && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
{
    if (obj == null) { return null; }

    Type type = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(property.Name);

    if (info == null) { return null; }
    var v = info.GetValue(obj, null);

    if (v != null)
        GetItems(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-examine-and-instantiate-generic-types-with-reflection

I am not sure if what you are looking for is going to work because in you EF you are configuring the classes as ComplexType. I am not sure the class itself knows its a complexType. You might end up creating a method on the DBcontext...

Comment: I'm not working with EF. These are classes that are filled with data sent by another application. I see a posible solution here: http://mcgivery.com/c-reflection-get-property-value-of-nested-classes. If this solve my problem I post here.